# How to group HKStatistics by hour?

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit, hksamplequery

I'm trying to extract step data from HealthKit.

I want to create a summary of step data grouped by hour. Currently, I can extract all of the samples of data between a date range provided by `NSPredicate` with `HKSampleQuery`. I could also get a sum of the step count between a date range with `HKStatisticsQuery`.

What I am asking is if there is a way to sum group the samples or statistics by hour. In SQL I would write something like this:

`SELECT HOUR(date), SUM(steps) FROM healthkit WHERE date BETWEEN 'blah' AND 'blah' GROUP BY 1;`

Am I seriously going to have to query HKStatistics 24 x 31 times to write the last month of step data grouped by hour? Because that seems rather inefficient, especially with how the `resultsHandler` is implemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use an `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` where you can perform grouping by time intervals. An example stub code would be:

```
NSDate *startDate, *endDate, *anchorDate; // Whatever you need in your case    
HKQuantityType *type = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];

// Your interval: sum by hour
NSDateComponents *intervalComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
intervalComponents.hour = 1;

// Example predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:fromDate endDate:toDate options:HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate];

HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:type quantitySamplePredicate:predicate options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum anchorDate:anchorDate intervalComponents:intervalComponents];
    query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *result, NSError *error) {
        // do something with the results
    };
[healthStore executeQuery:query];
```

You can read more details in the [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/HealthKit/Reference/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery/initWithQuantityType:quantitySamplePredicate:options:anchorDate:intervalComponents:)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The predicate may not be necessary, as inside the `initialResultsHandler` is a method called `enumerateStatisticsFromDate: toDate:`. What I wonder is if the result object is just a database pointer, or whether the query loads all of the data into memory? Apple's documents seem to use a nil predicate.

Comment: @AndyM Looks like passing nil for the predicate returns all data, so might be best to run the predicate with a start / end date first, so that enumerateStatisticsFromDate:toDate has a smaller dat set to filter. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKStatisticsCollectionQuery/initWithQuantityType:quantitySamplePredicate:options:anchorDate:intervalComponents: